# CS0266 cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>' to 'string'

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie to C#. When I run this program, I'm getting a compile type error

> CS0266 cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'

Is my syntax wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "Hello";
        s = s.Concat("World");
    }
}
```

Comment: suggested reading: **[Enumerable.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netcore-3.1)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You getting this error because the `Concat` function you have called is from LINQ. See here [Enumerable.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netcore-3.1). As a string is basically an enumeration of characters.

You have a variety of options to concatenate strings.

1. Just the + operator

```
string s = "Hello";
s = s + "World";
```

Or shorthand:

```
string s = "Hello";
s += "World";
```

2. static `Concat` function from string

```
string s = "Hello";
s = string.Concat(s, "World");
```

3. String Interpolation

```
string s = "Hello";
s = $"{s}World";
```

Answer (score 2):

`Concat` is a Linq extension method that allows to concat two `IEnumerable<char>`, so you need to write that to convert the resulting array in a string:

```
s = new string(s.Concat("World").ToArray());
```

Here the `s` value as an array of chars, that is an `IEnumerable<char>`, is executing the `Concat` method on it using the same thing for the string provided as parameter (an array of chars).

But you may prefer writing, with a space, this standard `string` concatenation:

```
s += " World";
```

That is the same of:

```
s = s + " World";
```

[Enumerable.Concat(IEnumerable, IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat)

Answer (score 0):

No need to go for complex and advanced techniques being a newbie.

In this scenario, concatenation can be done in simple way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "Hello";
        s = s + "World";
    }
}
```